# ibm watson Visual Recognition aborting retraining due to exception during custom classifier with java-sdk?

Tags: java, classification, watson, visual-recognition

```
{

"classifier_id": "lassifier_Class_1216362619",

"name": "name_Classifier",

"owner": "5765e64f-3c32-4aed-a424-75ddc38affbu",

"status": "ready",

"created": "2017-05-11T09:00:03.531Z",

"classes": [

    {"class": "class_1"},

    {"class": "class_2"},

    {"class": "class_3"},

],

"retrained": "2017-05-11T11:49:39.106Z",

"explanation": " aborting retraining due to exception during feature download. "  }
```

Salut, during the update classifier the retraining has failed and the response body of get: /v3/classifiers/ {classifier_id} :
explanation : "aborting retraining due to exception during feature download."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What this message means is that during retraining the system was unable to find all the feature data it extracted in previous training requests. This could be a problem in the system, but it can also happen if you "opted out" of storing these features and image data by setting the header parameter X-Watson-Learning-Opt-Out to true or 1 in the original POST /classifiers or intermediate retraining requests.

If you did not use this opt out header, please let me know, and I can investigate further.

Comment: My scenario is to lead to training the classifier it with zip files larger than 256 M.
And to do that, I try to train the classifier with iteration in each iteration contains 250 M.
The first iteration of updated its march , and the training carried out with success but next iteration  it is blocked.

Comment: hi,
I add the definition of the X-Watson-Learning-Opt-Out header parameter to true , but it still the same exception.

Comment: Allow me to clarify - the default value of X-Watson-Learning-Opt-Out is false, which is what you want.  If you set it to true, you are opting out of having your images persisted, so the system will NOT be able to retrain your classifier.  But I assume now that you had not set this header value in your previous requests, so that would not explain why you got the error message "aborting retraining due to exception during feature download."

Comment: I looked into our logs and found that there was an internal error when persisting the features for future retraining of your model.  So unfortunately, this classifier will not be retrainable.  If you start over, and train the original set of images again, it could succeed and your new classifier would then be retrainable.  Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: I want to try with input data (with images resolution 320 x 320 ) .
I apologize for the inconvenience